How to prevent generation of multiple Excel task pane instances
I have situation where I am employing a custom task pane in conjunction with a command ribbon:

The task pane is correctly presented when I execute the New or Open buttons, however I need to suppress additional task pain instances when execute the Load button.  The load button is just supposed to populate the existing task pane with the header content from a .csv file.  This works as expected until I execute the Apply button on the task pane.  The code underneath the Apply button generates a new WorkBook, and updates some range content.  The code generated workbook is then closed.  Now when I execute Load, a new task pane instance is presented and the .CSV header content is loaded into this task pane instead of the original.  I need to prevent this 2nd task pane instance from happening and ensure that the CSV content gets written to the existing task pane.  Below is the code executed by the command buttons I refer to:
From the command ribbon:
Private Async Sub btnSubstationLoad_Click(sender As Object, e As RibbonControlEventArgs) Handles btnSubstationLoad.Click

     'Load the csv file so that we can obtain the substation name
     Dim fDialog As New OpenFileDialog
     Dim path As String = Nothing

     Try

          SetTaskPaneOpen()

          If fDialog.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
               path = fDialog.FileName
          End If

          Globals.ThisAddIn.StatusBarUpdate("Loading substation data.  Please wait...")

          Globals.ThisAddIn.LoadCSV(path)
          Globals.ThisAddIn.CsvPath = path

          Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationName = Globals.ThisAddIn.Substations(0).Location
          Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationAlias = Globals.ThisAddIn.Substations(0).SubAlias
          Globals.ThisAddIn.INN = Globals.ThisAddIn.Substations(0).INN
          Globals.ThisAddIn.LicenceArea = Globals.ThisAddIn.Substations(0).LicenceArea

          'Store the relevant substation alias, INN and Substation Name 
          'populate the substation detail fields with this information
          Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.txtSubstationName.Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationName
          Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.txtLicenceArea.Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.LicenceArea

          If Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationType = "Secondary" Then
               Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.rbSecondary.Checked = True
          End If

          If Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.rbPrimary.Checked Then
               Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.txtUniqueSubstationId.Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.INN
          Else
               Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.txtUniqueSubstationId.Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationAlias
          End If

          'Now set the file loaded flag
          Globals.ThisAddIn.FileLoaded = True

          'Force a delay so that the user can see the change to the status bar
          Await Task.Delay(3000)

          Globals.ThisAddIn.StatusBarUpdate("Ready")

     Catch ex As Exception
          'Now set the file loaded flag
          Globals.ThisAddIn.FileLoaded = False
          Throw
     End Try


End Sub

 Private Sub SetTaskPaneOpen()
      Globals.ThisAddIn.TpSpenTagManager.Visible = True

      'Set the default tag convention
      Globals.ThisAddIn.TagConvention = _utl.GetSetting("TagConvention")
      If Globals.ThisAddIn.TagConvention = "Legacy" Then
           Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.rbLegacy.Checked = True
           Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.rbNew.Checked = False
      Else
           Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.rbNew.Checked = True
           Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.rbLegacy.Checked = False
      End If

      'Populate the user control with relevant repository information (minus the Change Reference that is input by the user)
      Globals.ThisAddIn.UcSpenTagManager.txtFilePath.Text = Globals.ThisAddIn.RepositoryRoot
      'Reset the csvpath ready for a new substation
      Globals.ThisAddIn.CsvPath = ""

 End Sub

From the Apply button on the Task Pane:
Private Sub btnApply_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnApply.Click

   Dim wb As Workbook
   Dim excelName As Excel.Name
   Dim instanceFolder As String
   Dim instanceTime As String = dtpTimeOfChange.Value.ToString(Globals.ThisAddIn.PatternTimeFormat)
   Dim filePart As String = instanceTime & "_" &
                                      Me.txtChangeReference.Text & "_" &
                                      Me.txtUniqueSubstationId.Text & "_" &
                                      _utl.SafeFileName(Me.txtSubstationName.Text, " ") & "_" &
                                      Me.txtVoltageLevel.Text

   instanceFolder = Me.txtFilePath.Text & "\" &
                            instanceTime & "_" &
                            Me.txtChangeReference.Text & "_PIAttributeBatchUpdate" & "\" & filePart


   'Generate the tag management folder structure underneath the specified working folder
   'if it doesn't already exist
   '<yyyyMMdd_hhmm>_<SBM Reference>_<busbar number>_<substation name>_<voltage>
   If Not Directory.Exists(instanceFolder) Then
        Directory.CreateDirectory(instanceFolder)
   End If

   Globals.ThisAddIn.InstanceFolder = instanceFolder

   'Now copy the file into place and open in Excel
   File.Copy(Globals.ThisAddIn.TemplatePath, instanceFolder & "\" & filePart & ".xlsm")

   'If CSV file has been loaded then clone the file in the instance folder
   If Globals.ThisAddIn.CsvPath <> "" Then
        _utl.CloneFile(Globals.ThisAddIn.CsvPath, instanceFolder & "\" & filePart & ".csv")
        'Update the csv path to the new file name so that the correct reference is delivered to the template
        Globals.ThisAddIn.CsvPath = instanceFolder & "\" & filePart & ".csv"
   End If

   Dim xlb As Excel.Workbook
   Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
   Dim rng As Excel.Range

   xlb = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Workbooks.Open(instanceFolder & "\" & filePart & ".xlsm", True)

   If rbPrimary.Checked Then
        Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationType = "Primary"
   Else
        Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationType = "Secondary"
   End If

   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("TagConvention", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = Globals.ThisAddIn.TagConvention
   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("SubstationType", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = Globals.ThisAddIn.SubstationType

   'add rng updates for ExportPath, BatchPath, Voltage, License Area and 
   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("CsvPath", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = Globals.ThisAddIn.CsvPath
   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("ExportPath", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = _utl.SplitPath(Globals.ThisAddIn.ExportPath, 0)
   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("BatchPath", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = _utl.SplitPath(Globals.ThisAddIn.BatchPath, 0)
   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("Voltage", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = Globals.ThisAddIn.Voltage
   rng = _utl.GetNamedRange("LicenseArea", xlb.Names)
   rng.Value = Globals.ThisAddIn.LicenceArea
End Sub

Ok... so some additional content surrounding the observed functionality.  So long as I don't exexute the Apply button, I can continue to load CSV content into the visible task pane.  However, when I click the Apply button and close the new workbook that is generated as part of the Apply process, and go back to load a new CSV file, If I place a break point on the SetTaskPaneOpen method and check the content of the user controls in the task pane, the controls are all empty, but should in fact still hold the values from the previous CSV load.  A new task pane instance has obviously been generated, despite the fact that no code has been executed to explicitly trigger new instance.

To address the issue of preventing multiple task panes from opening when executing the Load button and ensuring that the CSV content gets written to the existing task pane, you need to check if the task pane is already open before attempting to create or show a new one. The issue likely stems from the fact that SetTaskPaneOpen might be creating or showing a new instance each time it's called.

A quick pro tip: we ask that post authors do not sign their posts here. The profile card is considered sufficient in terms of signature.

@W_O_L_F:  Have edited the post with some additional observed functionality

Could you try the following, making taskPane a singleton. I have not tested...
Private _taskPane As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane

Public ReadOnly Property TaskPane() As Microsoft.Office.Tools.CustomTaskPane
    Get
        If _taskPane Is Nothing Then
            _taskPane = Me.CustomTaskPanes.Add(New UcSpenTagManager(), "Task Pane Title")
            _taskPane.Visible = True
        End If
        Return _taskPane
    End Get
End Property

Public Sub ShowTaskPane()
    Me.TaskPane.Visible = True
End Sub

and then change :
Private Sub SetTaskPaneOpen()
    Globals.ThisAddIn.ShowTaskPane()
....

